# Can't turn off gpio pins

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python

I recently installed raspbian on my RPi and i have experience in Python so I decided to play with GPIO pins. As soon as i connected my led to the 4th pin(5V) and 5th pin(GND) it turned on and I couldn't stop it. That happens on the other pins too. How do i turn this off?

Comment: Probably by using the correct pins.  What are the 4th and 5th pins.  Have a look at the table at the end of http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/.  Which pins are you actually using?

Comment: I can't find anything there for RPi B+

Comment: Last table, 40 pin expansion header.  Note, you need a series resistor with a LED or it might burn out.

Comment: I am using pins 4 and 6 just like I said

Comment: No you didn't, you said 4th pin and 5th pin.  If you connect to 5V and ground the LED will stay on.  If you want to switch the LED connect it to a GPIO and ground.  Then switch the GPIO on and off.

Comment: Do not burn your RPi, follow one of the multiple 'how to' or basic wiring PI before connecting anything to your 40 pin connector. GPIO are in/out ports that software can turn to (on) +3v3 or (off) ground. You should avoid using 5v0 when dealing with GPIO ports. The port load should be limited, so a 220ohms or larger resistor must be in place. On and Off is a relative term: will depend on your wiring and use. Some GPIO pins can have special purpose like txd/rxd, sda/sc, use them as last resource.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are connecting your LED to a power supply and ground, what else should it do but light up (or burn, without a resistor)? In other words, you are not using any GPIO actually.

To be able to control when it goes on you will need to connect to an actual GPIO and then ground *or* power. You can then control the LED by setting the GPIO you use to high or low respectively. Note that you need at least one resistor (to protect the LED), but probably should use more to provide some protection against using it wrong (which might burn your hardware!). Refer to the various available how-tos on this. An example I like (with good follow-ups) is http://raspberrypi.powersbrewery.com/project-1-a-simple-led/ ...